# Why did I get 20 reputation without any upvote or bookmark?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, reputation, voting

I had got 20 reputation for [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/663980/). But, I wonder how I got reputation from that question because, that question claims that no one had upvoted neither downvoted. Even, no one had bookmarked it. So why did I get 20 reputation from that? Is that because that was my first question? Is that a bug?

If I got downvote then why my reputation didn't decrease?

Comment: @Qmechanic If there was downvote than why my reputation didn't decrease?

Comment: Hi Istiak. See my answer below.

Comment: Because the minimum reputation a user can have is 1, this means that reputation is technically not a state function of the number of upvotes/downvotes. It exhibits path-dependence. If at least one upvote occured first, the final reputation will be 17 instead of 21.

Comment: Also, note that bookmarking a question does not yield reputation to the asker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FWIW, the -4 negative reputation points for the 2 downvotes (which were cast before the upvotes) were exceptionally not counted because that would have resulted in a total non-positive reputation for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has been upvoted twice and downvoted twice. The "net votes" on the post is thus 0, making it look like there is no vote at all. Users with the [Established User Privilege](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) (1000 reputation) can view vote counts.

So, you gained 20 reputation by 2 upvotes on your post but these were not visible to you because there were also 2 downvotes. These should also each have removed 2 of your reputation, which you should be able to see.

Comment: If there was downvote than why my reputation didn't decrease? I was thinking the same.. But, when I saw my reputation didn't decrease that's why I thought there might be some problem here.